# How to use UPSERT/Merge stored procedure on one to many Join columns. Both Source and Target tables has two one to many tables

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, merge, upsert

I have a requirement where as Source and Target table structure as follows.

Source:

```
CREATE TABLE S_Products
(
       ProductID INT PRIMARY KEY,
       ProductName VARCHAR(100),
) 
    
CREATE TABLE S_SubProducts
(
       SubProductID INT PRIMARY KEY,
       SubProductName VARCHAR(100),
       ProductID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES S_Products(ProductID)
) 

CREATE TABLE S_SubSubProducts
(
       SubSubProductID INT PRIMARY KEY,
       SubSubProductName VARCHAR(100),
       SubProductID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES S_SubProducts(SubProductID)
)
```

Target:

```
CREATE TABLE T_Products
(
    ProductID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductName VARCHAR(100),
) 
        
CREATE TABLE T_SubProducts
(
    SubProductID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    SubProductName VARCHAR(100),
    ProductID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES T_Products(ProductID)
) 
    
CREATE TABLE T_SubSubProducts
(
    SubSubProductID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    SubSubProductName VARCHAR(100),
    SubProductID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES T_SubProducts(SubProductID)
)
```

Have tried below stored procedure, but not sure how to work with join tables,

```
MERGE T_Products AS Target
USING S_Products AS Source ON Source.ProductID = Target.ProductID

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
    INSERT (ProductID, ProductName) 
        VALUES (Source.ProductID,Source.ProductName);
    INSERT INTO T_SubProducts
        (SELECT *  
         FROM S_SubProducts s_s 
         INNER JOIN Target T ON s_s.ProductID == T.ProductID);
    INSERT INTO T_SubSubProducts
        (SELECT * 
         FROM S_SubSubProducts s_s 
         INNER JOIN T_SubProducts T_s ON s_s.SubProductID == T_s.SubProductID);

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
        SET Target.ProductName = Source.ProductName

    UPDATE O
        SET O.SubProductName = C.SubProductName
        FROM S_SubProducts C 
        JOIN T_SubProducts O ON C.ProductID = O.ProductID;

    UPDATE O
      SET O.SubSubProductName = C.SubProductName
      FROM S_SubSubProducts C 
      JOIN T_SubSubProducts O ON C.SubSubProductName = O.SubSubProductName;
END
```

But is this good approach in MERGE statement? or the above hits performance issue. Is there any alternate good ways to perform merge upsert in join tables. Please help.

Or is it a good practice to have 3 merge upsert stored procedure because of 3 tables?

Comment: You cannot insert or update multiple tables with `MERGE` (or any other command), the target table mentioned on the first line is the one being modified. You could perhaps `OUTPUT` data from the `MERGE` and use that in other merges or inserts

Comment: Is there any other ways we could leverage join tables using upsert sp?

Answer (score -1):

Your approach will probably work, but it's very dependent on the table schemas not changing. If possible, I would consider using identity columns in the target tables to enforce the foreign key relationships.

You could add a condition on the 'WHEN MATCHED' part to not update when the ProductNames are not changed to avoid updating all rows in all three tables.

I would not use SELECT * when inserting in case the table structure changes.

Comment: Thanks mike6383, as for as i know the source and target tables columns is same its not going to change. But i feel somehow tables T_SubProducts & T_SubSubProducts are getting isolated from these stored procedure. Because the whole SP does take target as only T_Products right.